# Why is the off-diagonal summation notation for the Gini index used only in classification problems with more than 2 classes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, gini

The formula for the Gini index as a node impurity measure can be written as:

$Gini(q)= \sum_{k=1}^M p_{qk}(1-p_{qk})$

Where $q$ is the node and $M$ represents the number of classes. Why can we only use this notation:

$Gini(q)=  \sum_{k \neq k'}p_{qk}p_{qk'}$

According to my class notes, when the number of classes, $M$, is greater than 2. Why can we not use this formula for 2 classes:

$Gini(q)= \sum_{k=1}^M p_{qk}(1-p_{qk})$

$= (p_{q1}(p_{q2}) + (p_{q2}(p_{q1})$

$=p_{q1}p_{q2} + p_{q2}p_{q1}$

$=2p_{q1}p_{q2}$

We can then show the same for the second equation is equivalent:

$Gini(q)= \sum_{k \neq k'}p_{qk}p_{qk'}$

$=p_{q1}p_{q2} + p_{q2}p_{q1}$

$=2p_{q1}p_{q2}$

Note: J > 2 as suggested on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity